# iPhone Push Notification - How to use default sound

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I have implemented whole push notification service for my application using [easyapns](http://www.easyapns.com/).

I have implemented the server part using php and using the default php classes provided by easyapns.

Now, from server (php file), i am passing sound file name like :

```
$apns->addMessageSound('bingbong.aiff');
```

And I am including this 'bingbong.aiff' file in iPhone's Resource folder.

But Now I have a query that is it possible to play a default in-built sound of iPhone device instead of specify it externally ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally `$apns->addMessageSound('default');` should do the trick.